# VBA userform combobox that is list of outlook contact names and command button to search for matching contact home phone number when name selected

Tags: vba, printing, outlook, contacts

I am trying to make a userform that loads all of your outlook contacts full name into a combo box and then based on what name is selected their phone number that matches that name will print in another textbox. After the name is selected how do you then go back to get the phone number and print it to the textbox?

This is copied code to put outlook contact names into combobox, maybe at the same time add item that is the phone number to a combobox instead of textbox but then how do you match the information to the right name? The idea is it makes a phone message sheet that you then e-mail to the person the message is for and this would help to see if the person has called before without manually going to look up their number or asking for it again

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim MyOLApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Namespace
Dim myContacts As Items
Dim myContact As ContactItem
Dim newfax As MailItem
Set myNameSpace = MyOLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myContacts = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items

ComboBox1.Clear
For Each myContact In myContacts
  ComboBox1.AddItem myContact.FullName
  ComboBox1.Column(1, ComboBox1.ListCount - 1) = myContact.FullName
Next

Set myContacts = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set MyOLApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: For your first question, you could display all contacts in a multi-column ListBox in ```UserForm1```. The user can choose the contact of its choice to query for info. To do this, copy the line where you wrote ```myContact.FullName``` in column 1 of ComboBox1, and change it to write ```myContact.PrimaryTelephoneNumber``` in column 2 and ```myContact.Email1Adress``` in column 3. This will display FullName, PhoneNumber and EMailAddress side by side. Look at documentation of ```ContactItem``` for more properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem

Comment: What do you actual want to do/display once the user has selected a contact ? It's not very clear in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, iterating over all items in the Contacts folder is not really a good idea. That can be a time-consuming operation, so the Outlook UI may be frozen until it is finished. Instead, you may consider using tables in Outlook.

The Table represents a read-only dynamic rowset of data in a Folder or Search object. You can use [Folder.GetTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.gettable) or [Search.GetTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.search.gettable) to obtain a Table object that represents a set of items in a folder or search folder. If the Table object is obtained from [Folder.GetTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.gettable), you can further specify a filter (in [Table.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table.restrict)) to obtain a subset of the items in the folder. If you do not specify any filter, you will obtain all the items in the folder.

By default, each item in the returned Table contains only a default subset of its properties. You can regard each row of a Table as an item in the folder, each column as a property of the item, and the Table as an in-memory lightweight rowset that allows fast enumeration and filtering of items in the folder. Although additions and deletions of the underlying folder are reflected by the rows in the Table, the Table does not support any events for adding, changing, and removing of rows. If you require a writeable object from the Table row, obtain the Entry ID for that row from the default `EntryID` column in the Table and then use the [GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method of the [NameSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace) object to obtain a full item, such as a [MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) or [ContactItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem), that supports read-write operations. For more information on default columns in a Table, see [Default Properties Displayed in a Table Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/default-properties-displayed-in-a-table-object).

So, you may retrieve the table object with a contact's full name and `EntryID` which can be used to get the actual item if selected. Or just get the required properties into the table object, so you don't need to get the actual item instance in the code. Well, it depends on your needs...